# Use static class as datasource

Tags: c#, winforms

I have static class which contains data, i wish to use static class as datasource in datagridview.

But datasource property only accepts object. How can i set static class as datasource?

Comment: Use a singleton http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: Write a wrapper class that provides public Properties for the `datagridview` and uses the static class as it's data source.  Your main application can create instances of this class to bind against your form whenever it needs one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. But you could make it a Singleton:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static MyClass _instance;
    public static MyClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null) { _instance = new MyClass(); }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private MyClass() { }
}
```

and then reference it like `MyClass.Instance` for the data source.