# Binding Checkbox to a Shared Property in a custom class

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

So this should be simple I guess, but I have never done this.

Got a form on which I have a checkbox. I want this check box to be directly linked to a custom class's Boolean property, but somehow this does not work.

```
Public Class someClass
    Private Shared _Filter_Neighbor_6X1 As Boolean = True
    Shared Property Filter_Neighbor_6X1() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _Filter_Neighbor_6X1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Boolean)
            _Filter_Neighbor_6X1 = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class GameGUI
    Private Sub GameGUI_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    chk_FilterAll.DataBindings.Add("Checked", someClass, "Filter_Neighbor_6X1")
    end sub
End Class
```

The above does not work. It complains the "someClass" is a class.

I also tried:

```
chk_FilterAll.DataBindings.Add( _
    New Binding("Checked", someClass, "Filter_Neighbor_6X1", _
                False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, False))
```

which hangs the app on start.

any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bind to a Shared property. You need to remove the Shared modifier from the property, create an instance of the class, and use that instance for the data binding. Your class would look something like this:

```
Public Class someClass
    Private _Filter_Neighbor_6X1 As Boolean = True
    Public Property Filter_Neighbor_6X1() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _Filter_Neighbor_6X1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Boolean)
            _Filter_Neighbor_6X1 = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Then you can do something like:

```
Dim instanceOfSomeClass As New someClass()
chk_FilterAll.DataBindings.Add("Checked", instanceOfSomeClass, "Filter_Neighbor_6X1")
```

Note that if you don't have extra logic under the `Get` or `Set` of the property, you can get rid of the backing field and convert it to an Auto-Implemented (shorthand) property:<sup>*</sup>

```
Public Property Filter_Neighbor_6X1 As Boolean = true
```

Moreover, if you don't want to create an instance of the class each time, you can [make it a Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27839226/4934172):

```
Public Class someClass
    Private Shared _instance As someClass

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance As someClass
        Get
            If _instance Is Nothing Then _instance = New someClass()
            Return _instance
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property Filter_Neighbor_6X1 As Boolean = True
End Class
```

Then, you can use it directly like this:

```
chk_FilterAll.DataBindings.Add("Checked", someClass.Instance, "Filter_Neighbor_6X1")
```

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>You probably *do* need extra logic in this particular case in order to notify the change of the property so that the control can reflect that change. Check the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56925310/4934172) for more info.</sub>

Comment: Hello Ahmed. Thanks for the explanation! i'll give that a try here in a little, and i probably will want to go with your last sample (Singleton). I have to see how removing the 'shared' will effect my code, since i change these properties throughout code from different classes. I let you know how it turns out. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Gunnar If you don't want to remove the `Shared` modifier, you can create an additional `ReadOnly` property which returns the value of the Shared one. Check [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56925310/4934172).

Comment: Hi Ahmed. I went with your 1st post and implemented the Singleton 'trick' (i like that fix), changed all my subs/functions and calls accordingly and removed the shared. it wasn't as bad as i thought - there were about 100 changes. And... it worked beautifully! Thank you for your quick help with this!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to get rid of the `Shared` modifier, you can add a read-only property which returns the value of the Shared one:

```
Public Class someClass
    ' ...
    ' ...

    ' TODO: Remember to use a different name.
    Public ReadOnly Property MyNonSharedProperty As Boolean
        Get
            Return Filter_Neighbor_6X1
        End Get
    End Property   
End Class
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Dim instanceOfSomeClass As New someClass()
chk_FilterAll.DataBindings.Add("Checked", instanceOfSomeClass, "MyNonSharedProperty")
```

Or with the Singleton approach (check the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56924298/4934172) for details):

```
chk_FilterAll.DataBindings.Add("Checked", someClass.Instance, "MyNonSharedProperty")
```

---

**However,** please note that if you're implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your class<sup>*</sup>, you'll need to notify the change of the read-only property as well as the Shared one when the latter gets changed.

**Full implementation:**

```
Public Class someClass
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    ' ##################################
    ' Optional: Add Singleton logic here
    ' ##################################

    Private _Filter_Neighbor_6X1 As Boolean = True
    Public Property Filter_Neighbor_6X1() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _Filter_Neighbor_6X1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Boolean)
            _Filter_Neighbor_6X1 = Value
            NotifyPropertyChanged()
            ' TODO: Remember to change the name of the property.
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MyNonSharedProperty")
        End Set
    End Property

    ' TODO: Remember to use a different name.
    Public ReadOnly Property MyNonSharedProperty As Boolean
        Get
            Return Filter_Neighbor_6X1
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName()> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

<sup>*</sup>  <sub>Which is something you should do when using the class as a DataBinding source.</sub>